# Intersection of the unit (geodesic) sphere with the $y$-axis

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have a question about this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7ZLB.jpg) of Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry. If we consider $S_1((0,1))$, the image of the unit sphere in $T_{(0,1)}G$ under the map $\exp_{(0,1)}$, at which points does it intersect the $y$ axis? Which results can we use to know this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direction: You are given that the $y$-axis is the image of an geodesic. So consider

$$\gamma (t) = (0,1-t), \  \  \text{where } t\in (-\infty, 1).$$

This is a curve in the manifold which might not be a geodesic (due to the wrong parametrization), but anyway the image is that of a geodesic. Now solve for

$$ 1 = \int_0^s \|\gamma'(t)\| dt$$

should give you two values $s_1, s_2$, and $1-s_1, 1-s_2$ will be what you need (why?)

Comment: I've been looking for a result in do Carmo that I can use but I still don't know which one.

Comment: You don't need anything more than the definition. In the above, do you know what is $\|\gamma\|$? @Sajindia

Comment: It's $\langle \gamma, \gamma \rangle^{1/2}$.

Comment: You missed a $\dot{}$, it's $\sqrt{\langle\dot \gamma, \dot\gamma\rangle}$. You can compute this directly in this case. @Sajindia

Comment: But then $\| \gamma^. \| = \langle  \gamma^{..}, \gamma^{..} \rangle$?

Comment: My bad, I mean $\|\gamma '\| = \sqrt{\langle \gamma', \gamma'\rangle}$. You can calculate this term directly. @Sajindia

Comment: I know it's easy to calculate it but I don't know why this gives the intersection points.

Comment: Note that $\int_0^s \|\gamma\| dt = d((0,1), (0,1-s))$. @Sajindia

Comment: Do we need to use that exp is an isometry?

Comment: $exp$ is in general not an isometry, but we have that the unit sphere in the tangent plane will be mapped to $\{y\in G: d(y, (0,1) ) = 1\}$. @Sajindia

Comment: I get $\int_0^s \| \gamma'(t) \| dt = - \log(1-s)$.